# org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload does not seem to have method setProgressListener

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, apache-commons

The class `org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload` does not seem to have method `setProgressListener` in commons-fileupload version 1.2 or 1.2.2, yet it is referenced in examples provided for its use.

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it does, it's inherited from `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase`.

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/fileupload/tags/commons-fileupload-1.2.2/src/java/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadBase.java?revision=964209&view=co

See the very bottom of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your response; However would you know why I am getting a "The method setProgressListener(FileUploadListener) is undefined for the type ServletFileUpload" yet FileUploadListener implements ProgressListener?

Comment: @ehtearena Without seeing anything specific I wouldn't have any idea. My first assumption would be an incorrect `ProgressListener` import, but that's just a stab in the dark.

Comment: thanks; Please see the class file here: http://echo-systems.net/FileUploadListener.java

Comment: @ehtearena Still no clue, I'd need to actually try it.

Comment: Thanks, I know it will be an overkill; Let me see what I can do now that I know the method actually exists via inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use j query file upload, it is very good plugin, i have used that in my project.
http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

you can use following maven dependency for that

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

you can use jar of same version also

Comment: Thanks for sharing. However the main challenge is at the server side where I am employing Java (specifically apache-commons file upload method) to save the file on the server.